# Subform does not requery / Source is a linked table

Tags: subform

Setup:  One Access database (database "A") contains all of the forms, queries, macros, etc.  Two other Access databases (database "B" and "C"), each with the same collection of tables.  The source for a subform in "A" is linked to a table in either "B" or "C".  When I drop the linked tables in "B" and link to the tables in "C", refreshing the subform in "A" does not refresh the data from "C".  If I close and then open the form, the data in "C" is displayed.

It's behaving as though the subform is not acknowledging that the linked table has been dropped and relinked.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  After the vba routine relinked the tables, I added code to change the "RecordSource" property of the subform, and it automatically refreshed the data from the newly relinked table without issuing a ".requery" command.